# How to prevent Grunt to run on Heroku in a Sails.js App with pre-executed Grunt Pipeline?

Tags: heroku, gruntjs, sails.js

I tried to deploy my Sails.js WebApp on heroku and got these errors:

> ```
> app[web.1]: Grunt :: Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
> heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
> heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=704M(137.5%)
> heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
> ```

So I know I could run the uglify and other grunt tasks locally and then push the created ./tmp folder to heroku and delete the task from `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

What I did:

1:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js
$ git add ./tmp
```

2:

comment the tasks in `tasks/prod.js` out:

```
 grunt.registerTask('prod', [
   /* 'compileAssets',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'cssmin',
    'sails-linker:prodJs',
    'sails-linker:prodStyles',
    'sails-linker:devTpl',
    'sails-linker:prodJsJade',
    'sails-linker:prodStylesJade',
    'sails-linker:devTplJade'*/
  ]);
```

3:

```
$ git add tasks/prod.js
$ git commit -m "Am I doing it right?"
$ git push heroku master
```

But now the Sever doesn't start:

> ```
> app[web.1]: Grunt :: Done, without errors.
> app[web.1]: grunt hook loaded successfully.
> heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
> heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
> ```

**How can I run Grunt tasks locally and push the results to heroku without running those tasks again in a Sails.js app?**

Comment: Could it be that your app simply takes longer than 60 seconds to load on Heroku? If so you could take a look at [Heroku Forward](https://github.com/dblock/heroku-forward).

Comment: Hi, it's been a while since you asked this. Were you able to fix the issue? It's been a hit-and-miss issue in my case (sometimes the server starts up in time). But after a recent update, it always fails, pretty much the same way. Did you find a way around this issue?